# How do I convert a UL list item to a JSON object?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have a pane on my page that contains several `<ul>`'s , in each ordered list one of the list items are a lat-long object that has been stringified.  When I click on the ordered list title I need to convert the string to JSON object.

```
$.each(dealers, function (i, obj) {
    $listSelector.append("<ul class='dealer-summary-list'>" + "<li class='dealerName'>" + obj.title + "</li>" + "<li class='dealer-summary-listItem'>" + obj.address + "</li>" + "<li class='dealer-summary-listItem'>" + obj.locale + "</li>" + "<li class='dealer-summary-listItem'>" + obj.location.lat + ', ' + obj.location.lng + "</li>" + "<li class='dealer-summary-listItem'>" + obj.phone + "</li>" + "</ul>")
});
```

Comment: Bad syntax. `obj.location = JSON.parse(items.eq(3).text());` You want to parse the value instead of parsing the text() function.

Comment: the end result must be..."location = Object {lat: 41.321343, lng: -81.623383}" as it renders in the dom.  You are right but I should have been more clear...when I parse the value i get a string of "" 41.321343, -81.623383"

Comment: So the inspected element in the DOM should be "location = Object {lat: 41.321343, lng: -81.623383}"

Comment: what's the exact problem you are facing?

Comment: Create that object and parseFloat() the string. This is why ppl should learn JS before learning a bunch of libraries. Btw, the end result you want is already inside the dealers array. Use it.

Comment: In the ("#dealersList").on("click")...obj.location = items.eq(3).text(); is showing "41.321343, -81.623383" in the inspected element in the DOM...I need to convert it into an object so when I inspected it in the DOM it shows as ""location = Object {lat: 41.321343, lng: -81.623383}""

Comment: @Shilly...off-handed remarks aren't necessary but reading the post is.  The dealers list is hard coded and only provided as reference...the rendered items in the <ul> have click events.  When an item is clicked the value is then used...this  is the workflow needed for the desired result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assign a custom attribute to your UL element that indicates the index of corresponding dealer in the dealer array.

Instead of parsing the li elements, get the custom attribute and use it to retrieve the dealer object from array

Eg  in the elements creation script

```
  $.each(dealers, function (i, obj) {
  $listSelector.append("<ul dealerindex='"+i+ "'         class='dealer-summary-list'>" + "<li class='dealerName'>" + obj.title + "</li>" + "<li class='dealer-summary-listItem'>" + obj.address + "</li>" + "<li class='dealer-summary-listItem'>" + obj.locale + "</li>" + "<li class='dealer-summary-listItem'>" + obj.location.lat + ', ' + obj.location.lng + "</li>" + "<li class='dealer-summary-listItem'>" + obj.phone + "</li>" + "</ul>")
```

});

In the parsing script
        var idx = parseInt( $(this).attr("dealerindex"));
        var location= dealers[idx].location;

Comment: This is a good idea...I am working on the solution and I will let you know soon!

Comment: This was a very good idea...In the creation element i already used the index(i)....so I created a custom data-attribute and set the index on the click event to this.index...

Comment: $listSelector.append("<ul class='dealer-summary-list'>" + "<li class='dealer-summary-listItem' data-dealerIndex=" + i + ">" ......."

Comment: var i = $(this).index();